# How do I model a scene by using objects from other blend files?

Tags: modeling, workflow, blend-files

So I am trying to get how to use Blender. But I don't get its 'file system'. For example, My approach used to be if I was modeling a bedroom, I would create the walls and I would place boxes instead of furniture. I would save those files. As I modeled each piece of furniture I would overwrite each box file and it would start populating the room. Blender seems to save everything inside a single file, or am I doing it wrong? How do you guys do your library of models? Are they all 'scenes' just with the model/object? is there a preferred way of doing it? I could not find information about this... help...

Comment: You can put models in separate files and then have another files that contains the scene where the models are linked into. For an overview of a proper production pipeline of an animated short film made with Blender, you may want to watch [Andy's talk](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=aR3yNNGK_sc) from the Blender conference 2019.

Comment: THANKS! that sounds exactly like what I am looking for.

Comment: The relevant parts of the manual can be found [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/index.html?highlight=link).

Comment: @RobertGützkow Oh, sir, big thanks for sharing this, what a great talk!